# coding reactjs with the build in of html

Tags: html, reactjs

Im starting coding reactjs and im confusing how html5 work on reactjs. Do we need to build a separate html5 sheet or code html5 direct into jsx sheet?

Comment: Hey there friend! Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922) and how to post questions that include [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it currently stands, your question is way to vague for anyone to help you.

Comment: Also please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React is component based java-script lib. so on your html code just link jsx by `main.js` code structure. your xml code build and make application in the extension of **JSX** like `App.jsx` . [Refer here to build react app](https://medium.com/the-codelog/intro-to-react-js-a37696fd99af)

**index.html**

This is just regular HTML. We are setting div id = "app" as a root element for our app and adding index.js script which is our bundled app file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

   <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      <title>React App</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id = "app"></div>
      <script src = "index.js"></script>
   </body>

</html>
```

**App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            Hello World!!!
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

**main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```